# Web scraping using Python and Selenium, don't know how to get dynamic data

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to grab values from a table, but they're not in the HTML. However, they *are* in the HTML when I inspect them in the browser. I'm guessing that they're dynamically generated, but how do I capture them in Selenium or another way in Python?

Comment: you want just the tables, right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.predictit.org/Contract/7422/Will-Trump-veto-Russian-sanctions-bill-by-August-31#prices')

time.sleep(2)
tables = pd.read_html(driver.page_source) # returns list of dataframes
print(len(tables))
print(tables[2]) # this is table with YES
print(tables[3]) # this is the table with NO
```

This code fetches only the tables but you need to do some cleaning. You can read the docs for [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiWxLmf_LfVAhUGNI8KHZKFAp8QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.DataFrame.html&usg=AFQjCNEdNrNY461PFYQf9Z9EbcpcvboDCw)

Comment: That did the trick once I installed all the necessary modules. Thank you!

I'll have to look up what a "dataframe" is exactly.

Comment: For the record, you have to click on the Prices tab before this solution works. So, "elem = driver.find_element_by_id('getPrices')
elem.click()" needs to be in the code.

Comment: The `url` I opened, contains `#prices`. So I do not need to find any element.

Comment: That doesn't bring you to the prices tab, though. Well, it doesn't bring *me* to the prices tab, anyway. Update: Yeah, that didn't work in either Chrome or Firefox. I have to click Prices.

Comment: If it doesn't bring to prices tab then how I am able to read the tables. Because the tables exists in the source.

Comment: Wait, if you view source, the tables are there? Because they're not for me.

For example, if I search for "Buy Yes" in the source, I only find this: "<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm hidden-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#SignInModal">Buy Yes</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm visible-xs" onclick="window.location = '/Account/SignIn?ReturnUrl=/Contract/7422/Will-Trump-veto-Russian-sanctions-bill-by-August-31';">Buy Yes</button>"

Comment: And that was going straight to the url with #prices.

Comment: That's why I included `#prices` in the url

Comment: Well, that doesn't bring me to the Prices tab in any browser I have. The button has to be clicked first. No idea why that's different for you.

Comment: Strange. The code you provided only works for me with the button clicking added, otherwise I get an error. This may forever remain a mystery.